# Asp.Net MVC BundleConfig Comments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I did some searching on this but couldn't find out why, but in my project, commenting out a line in the `.Include()` breaks the entire `ScriptBundle`.  If I comment out one line, the other javascript files will not load.

Can you comment out individual bundles, or do you need to remove them and maybe put the comment below the code in case you need to put it back?

Ex.

This works:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
          "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
          "~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js",
          "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
          "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
```

---

This causes the other javascript files in the ScriptBundle not to get loaded.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
          "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
          // "~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js",
          "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
          "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
```

Comment: The other javascript files do not load, so bootstrap components do not work anymore, like the datepicker.

Comment: Commenting out a line like you show shouldn't be a problem. Check your rendered script sections -- If you see the bootstrap resources included on your page then the bundler is working. You commented out the multiselect plugin but did you also remove any code that uses it? Does the datepicker have a dependency on it? Are there script errors on the console?

Comment: D'oh!  @Jasen is correct.  I had some scripting that was still looking for `.multiselect`, so it caused the other javascript, like `.datepicker` to stop working.  Post this as an answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commenting out a line like you show shouldn't be a problem. Check your rendered script sections -- If you see the bootstrap resources included on your page then the bundler is working.

If your other scripts stop working then this indicates a problem with your javascript still referencing the removed bundle resource.

Answer (score 0):

of course you can comment some lines (as you did), but remember you need to recompile your project to get affected

Comment: I just tried that.  I commented out the line, and then rebuilt the Project and the entire Solution.  It does load the other javascript files, but for some reason the other components, not related to the one I commented out, do not work anymore.  Once I uncomment that line, it starts working again.

Comment: @L_7337 Scripts might have dependency to each other, (not in the case of you) just for being sure right click on page and view source, the corresponding script shouldn't be there, if it is not there commenting is working fine.